# Display row wise actions in struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.3.3?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

How to display rowaction's i..e, edit,delete in every row the grid using  struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.3.3.Pleas check the image[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.I added jquery.frmtter javascript file and add parameter as  actions in gridcolumn.ftl. But this is not implemented in the current version struts2-jquery-grid plugin.Its working for me